# How to find tangent of a an equation

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve this question by using the slope of a curve at a point formula. How do you find an equation for each tangent to the curve y = 1 / (x-1) that has a slope of -1? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = -1$ for $x$.